# Event Listener can bind with function class

Tags: javascript

I am not getting proper output and here function is described to call explicitly.
i don't want to bind an html Object, i want to bind it with a function class object.
here is the source:-

```
function createClass()
{
   this.v = 5;
}
var obj = new createClass();
  obj.bind('click',function(){
      alert("hi");
  });
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: You're trying to bind the click event for an empty object.  so better assign it with elements and then do it.

Comment: can u explain your question in detail?

Comment: Where's the jQuery? Also, [`bind` is a method of `Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), not `Object`. This triggers the error - *TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bind'*

Comment: i am trying to bind a event to an object of a function class.

Comment: @Pankaj—there are no classes in javascript. There are Functions that can be used as constructors to create objects (instances) that inherit from the constructor's *prototype*. *bind* is a method for setting a function's *this* keyword to a particular object (or any value in strict mode). It has nothing to do with DOM elements unless you are using a library, where *bind* may have a different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

try this, and make sure your object is not empty and JQuery is loaded!

```
// removing empty object
var obj = $('.availableClass');
obj.bind('click',function(){
  alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: obj.bind('click',function(){

Comment: Why wrap `obj` in `$()`, it's already a `jQuery` object?

Comment: yes phil Agree, corrected now

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
   alert($(this).text());
 });
$("#foo").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
obj.addEventListener && obj.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.debug("Hello");
});
```